# Getting first and last elements in aggregate query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to add first element's property "open" and last element's property "close" to the inner aggregation. Any one has idea how to do it?

The document looks as follows:

```
{
  "id": "1b73c03c-182e-4092-bf23-7fb6e2525586",
  "assetId": 5,
  "open": 143.345,
  "close": 143.355,
  "min": 143.335,
  "max": 143.355,
  "tS": "2017-04-10T18:24:00"
}
```

The code is:

```
 .Aggregations(a => a
                .DateHistogram("bars", st => st
                     .Field(o => o.TS)
                     .Interval(interval)
                     .MinimumDocumentCount(2)
                     .Aggregations(childAggs => childAggs
                        .Min("min", avg => avg.Field(p => p.Min))
                        .Max("max", avg => avg.Field(p => p.Max))
                    )
                )
            )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is not clear, what is the "open" and "last" properties you're talking about?

Comment: changed it. i need first and last element property included to aggregation.